# Android App Icon size too small

Tags: android, icons, mipmaps

I am working on a test android app. The problem I am having is that the app icon is very very small. I have added different sizes in different mipmap folder but the size is still the same = very tiny. I have tried to add large size in all of the folders but it didn't work either.

How to fix this?

Comment: Try putting them in drawable-**** folders.

Comment: I have done that aswell. Still not working...?

Comment: That might be due to the blank spaces present around the png image.

Answer (score 5):

Do you use the correct icon size?

Launcher icons (.Png)

```
48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
512 × 512 (Google Play store)
```

You could use Android Asset Studio for generate the Launcher Icons automatically

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: This is the website I have used to create them. I placed them in the different MipMap folders but the only one which works is the smallest one. Strane...