# App Icon on Device is too small

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, size

My problem is that the App Icon on my device looks way too small in comparison to the other apps. I read some solution on other questions, like this one [Android App Icon size too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980139/android-app-icon-size-too-small) but this doesn't seems to be my problem. In the Android Studio you can make a right click on "res" where you can find new --> image asset where you can create such a icon. it creates icons for all the different sizes like mdpi, hdpi and so on. So i thougt that i might display the app icon correctly but it doesn't. can anybody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to use [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html). Its very useful, fast and free. And thats what I use.
If your icon already has a shape, remember to set the shape to none. Hope it helps!

If you are getting the same results, I also recommend [this](http://makeappicon.com/) website, where I usually get "bigger" icons.

Comment: isn't this Launcher Icon Generator doing the same like the one in the android studio? do you add the zip context to the drawable or somewhere else?

Comment: Extract it and paste the res folder in your project folder.

Comment: ok, the second link works fine, thanks. but do you know why there the size is different?

Comment: Well, I don't think there is a standard size. e.g. I have a Zenfone and the Asus app icons have bigger sizes than the Google apps icons. Icons are free form, so its up to you how it is going to be.

Comment: @PrimožKralj Can you be more specific? Even though its an old question, it helped some people.

Comment: Say you have a square icon and you want to get a full-sized icon with rounded corners, without any padding. With the tools you specified here that is not possible - you first need to make rounded corners yourself in image editing software.
These tools may be helpful, but they do not solve the original problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. You need a tool to help you make the icon and this icon has to be bigger. Even though that was not the original question, you can solve it too. Just generate the icon on the first tool I recommended (rounded corners, if you will) then use the second one (with the icon image you generated) and it will make it bigger! Links: first -  https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html
Second - https://makeappicon.com/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 21):

In "Configure Image Asset", click "Legacy", change "Shape" from "Square" to "None", and the image padding will appear. Go back to "Foreground Layer" and resize the image to fill the padding.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the launcher icons generator puts there a small padding, that is the reason for smaller icons. On the other way it is recommended by Google team  [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons).

**Android expects product icons to be provided at 48dp, with edges at 1dp.**

All is on you to decide. In case the icon applies to whole square space - use padding, otherwise when small object is not square shape, rather fit to edges :)

Comment: this site is awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use any single image directly as `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`
It'll be shown correctly on old devices but on android 26+ it'll appear small

[image]

Use this approach to make the icon appear like `fitXY` scaleType for imageview, that is, it's corners can be clipped like cardview but it will not be shrinked

#### Step 1

Delete `ic_launcher` from `drawables` and paste it in `mipmap-xxhdpi-v4`
Add transparent padding of width/6 px to your launcher icon [online](https://onlinepngtools.com/add-png-border)

#### Step 2

Paste the second file as `ic_launcher_foreground`

[image: project view]

#### Step 3

Create ic_launcher.xml under res/mipmap-anydpi-v26 and add this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" />
    <background android:drawable="@color/colorTransparent"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

#### Step 4

Edit the manifest and use mipmap instead of drawable
[image: manifest]

Now your icon should not appear shrinked/zoomed
This is useful when your app icon can't be split into foreground/background eg some graphic image as app icon

#### How it works:

For API26+ devices, `mipmap-anydpi-v26` will take precedence over mipmap-xxhdpi-v4 and system will load icon from xml, which in turn, loads foreground from ic_launcher_foreground, automatically crop 2/3 of its size because it's 'adaptive icon'. (This is the reason we add padding of width/6 from all sides
For older devices the ic_launcher.webp will be used directly

Tested on API 21-31

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I fixed it like so:

Create the adaptive icon through Android Asset Studio. In the third tab you can select "Create Legacy Icon". Only this legacy one is going to be too small! The others will be fine.

So the thing I did was just to replace the icon_launcher.png files (this is the legacy icon).