# Removing the white background and having a full size app icon?

Tags: android, image, background, icons, transparency

I am finalising my app and what to set the app icon. However, I fail every time and tried so many app icon generators... I have my app icon which is 3000x3000 and has no background. Whenever I try to generate my app icons I select `sharpe` `none`. The result is always the same (you can find a screen below).

How can I have my app icon like the Google Maps icon or the clock icon?
I want to have my bee centered and the background simply should be cut of depending on the icon shape..

This is an website I have used e.g.: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html

My `AndroidManifest.xml` is also using the correct icon:

```
<application
  ..
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

[image]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/75049187/9752209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was recently asked, and the answers were it had to do with the new adaptive icons for Android 8.0
You will have to create your own adaptive icons, see https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive for instructions.
BTW, 3000 x 3000 icon is crazy, and has no reason. Legacy icons should be 48dp x 48dp, so highest resolution should be 192px x 192px.

Comment: Thanks - working! And yeah I know, but you can resize it ;)

Comment: Don't know what you mean about resizing it. 3000 x 3000 is a wasted few mb in memory (and 36mb when uncompressed), and doesnt even fit on a large  1920 x 1080 screen. It will only slow things down, as system has to allocate memory, and then shrink it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with your phone; see the gmail icon, it has also the same white background:
[see what they say about that here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/tmobile-s7-edge/help/how-rid-ugly-white-icon-backgrounds-t3559100)

3000x3000 is very big.

I think [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio) might help!