# android adaptive launcher icon on honor view 10 phone too large

Tags: android, adaptive-icon

I created adaptive icons for my app with Android Asset studio. The launcher icon looks good on emulators for Galaxy Nexus API 28, Nexus 5x API 24, Nexus 9 API 23, and on devices like Lenovo Phab 2 API 28, Samsung Galaxy S9+ API 26. However, the icon appears too large, overflowing the round icon bound in Honor view 10 API 28. Can anyone help fixing this issue?

Here are the steps I had go through. One foreground layer and one background layer in png format, each of size 1024 x 1024, were created. Then the icons were added by File>New>Image Asset>Configure Image Asset and filling the paths to the image assets. 
In the preview panel of the Configure Image Asset dialog, the icons look good for screen resolutions from mdpi to xxxhdpi. And the created png images under the mipmap* folders have the [correct sizes as here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrMdp.png). And my project has the [present structure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Yenyg5QD8hyFdd99abLXuH4RmuFRpoJx).

Before creating and adding these icons to the project, the default launcher icon provided by Android looked good on Honor View 10, noticing the first icon on the last row of [the screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fD5pARTQoae4mUXZBSsVTErmvlgRiNfC). But now it looked like the second icon on the last row of [the screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fD5pARTQoae4mUXZBSsVTErmvlgRiNfC).

I have read through the questions about android icon appearance problems like [android-launcher-icon-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768128/android-launcher-icon-size) and [app-icon-on-device-is-too-small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231439/app-icon-on-device-is-too-small), but none of these problems seem relevant.

One peculiarity I have noticed is that among the virtual or actual devices  I have tested, only the Honor View 10 uses a round icon, while the others uses square or square round icons.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I suddenly realized the app launcher icon became normal on Honor View 10. In the past fortnight, I did not do anything such as upgrading the OS on Honor view 10 manually or updating the app. Today I uninstall and reinstall the app on View 10. The launcher icon looks good. So basically time solves the icon issue. On the other hand, I suspect there is some background automatic updates from Honor View 10, fixing the issue.