# Flutter Android launcher icon looks very small

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using the flutter_launcher_icons package to generate launcher icons for both Android and iOS. Everything looks great on iOS, but on Android the icon looks very tiny:

[image: Android]

It's the second one from the left. I've tried all kinds of things to get it to be bigger. I've tried several different source images to generate the icon, 512x512 and 900x900, but no matter what I do I can't get it to generate an icon as large as the others. I'm sure I'm missing something stupid here. This is my flutter_launcher_icons config:

```
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon_new2.png"
```

Comment: Please read https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-add-app-launcher-icons-in-flutter-bd92b0e0873a

Comment: I tried that guide as well, but the result is the same. Looks great on iOS, but on Android the icon is very small.

Comment: @cloudwalker Did you ever get it figured out?

Comment: Mine is the opposite. Android works flawlessly. iOs the icon is smaller (though not that small like yours) and it does not follow the background color i set.

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend you to use http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html to generate your launcher icon : you'll be able to reduce padding to get an icon as big as possible. When you hit download, this will generate a zip archive containing a `res` folder with a subfolder for each size.

Let's then put manually the Android launcher icon :
In your config, put `android: false` so the `flutter_launcher_icons` plugins stops generating icons for android, and paste your generated subfolders in `yourproject/android/res`

I encountered the same issue as you, looks like we followed the same tutorials/links.

EDIT : If you still encounter issues, this thread may help you (almost a duplicate) [App Icon on Device is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231439/app-icon-on-device-is-too-small/32519140)

Comment: where is config file

Answer (score 2):

For all the flutter android projects, for those who are still facing issues after generating icons from here, http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html follow the below steps,

1. Open your flutter project in Android Studio
2. Select the android folder and Right click
3. Select the option flutter->Open Android Module in Android Studio ( open in new window)
4. It will take a while, once its done, in the android project, right click on res->drawable folder, and create new image asset
5. Create the launcher icons using your image in this android studio wizard.

Once the launcher icons are created, build your apk or app bundle asusual from your flutter project.  It should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer of the user [TBG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8179249/tbg), in my case, the path where I had to put the res folder was in youproject/android/app/src/main/, replace what you have and voila, recompile your project.

Answer (score 0):

TBG suggestion worked well.  One thing to note, if you already replaced icon, your files in android "res" folder may be different from "ic_launcher" produced by IconKitchen.  And your bad icones generated by Flutter will still be used during build.

You can fix it by either renaming files from Kitchen before copying, or by reverting android:icon in AndroidManifext.xml

android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"