# Android icon doesn't fit

Tags: android

I've been experiencing an issue with creating an icon that fits in any size and shape. I use Studio to do it, but I must be doing something wrong, because there is a small padding in it.

I add my image asset as background layer with nothing in foreground layer.

I've tried to fix it by trimming it and using huge icon source 1920*1280.

When I changed to new theme it turned out that few other apps on my phone(other devs) have same poor icons.

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231439/app-icon-on-device-is-too-small)

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Creating an icon using foreground layer totally solves this issue.

[image]